# Socket.io only emits event sometimes

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I am using React Native to connect to Socket.io with a Node.js. As far as I'm aware, the fact that I'm using React Native is more or less indifferent, besides the fact that it means I must set `transports: ['websocket']` when connecting.

On the back-end, when prompted, the server fetches data from an API and then emits that data to a room via something similar to the following code:

```
async getData() {
    const data = await fetchData();
    io.of('/namespace').to('/room').emit('event', data);
}
```

The problem is that the event only seems to be emitted about 40% of the time or so.

I configured socket.io to log everything in the terminal. When the data transfer doesn't work, it looks like this: `socket.io-parser encoding packet [the data]`, then it says `socket.io-parser encoded [the data]` and doesn't log anything after that. When it does work, these two things are logged, but then it also logs `socket.io:client writing packet [the data]` afterwards. Another note is that all communications in which the server doesn't first have to fetch data from the API seems to be working correctly. I would appreciate if anybody had any ideas on how to resolve this, or any steps I could take to find a solution.

Comment: Is there possibly a timing issue where the connections in your room disappear (disconnect) while you're doing `fetchData()` so by the time you get the data, the socket.io connections are gone and then the `io.of('/namespace').to('/room')` finds no connections in the room to send to?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it'd be logged in the Terminal if that were to happen.

Comment: What kind of request handler is calling `getData()`?  Is it a form POST handler?  Can you show us the whole request handler that calls `getData()`?  I think we need to see more of the code context.  Without that, we're only able to make wild guesses.